# How do I deploy to a jailbroken device running ios 6.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I am learning iOS programming, is it possible to deploy my app to a jailbroken ios 6.1 device? if so please advice, thanks. btw,im using Xcode 4.6 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Comment: have you created provisioning profile of that device?

Comment: no I haven't paid the $99 fee to apple as yet

Comment: @Joseph, I'm guessing your real question is "How can I test my app on my own device?" In the description, you can say that it is jailbroken. You should re-write your question for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install appsync 5.0+ on your jailbroken device.
2. Download jailcoder from [HERE](https://mega.co.nz/#!aohhQThK!Bx68RwB3-THB1xx3KrFeMyZUkQRkZmTLxXXmWXIRmF8).
   Right click on JailCoder.app -> Show Package Contents, then from folder Resource.
3. Copy two certificate iPhone Developer.cer and iPhone Developer.p12 to your desktop.
4. Then CMD+Space and type Keychain ENTER (to open Keychain Access), from left view select login.
5. Click on File menu click on Import Items, choose iPhone Developer.cer to import. Choose always trust and give your system passward it asked.
6. Again click on File menu Click on import items, choose iPhone Developer.p12 to import.
7. now enter the password "jailcoder" and ignore error msg.
   That's it! Now try to build or archive your project.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi. Is this process tested in iOS 6 or 6.1 and XCode 4.6? I got the idea Jaicoder only worked for iOS 5.x and older versions of XCode.

Comment: @Joncom Thank you, I'll try it then. What is the version o Jailcoder you are using? (If it's got a version, I didn't try to install the program yet).

Comment: @jbssm Not sure because I've since removed it. However I downloaded it from the link in step two, so if you click that link you'll maybe know which version I had. PS - Got everything working using a different method: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82896/how-to-compile-xcode-4-6-project-without-provisioning-profile-then-run-it-on-ja/82902